# Unable to load js file grails spring-security shows login denied

Tags: javascript, grails, spring-security, tinymce, cas

I am trying to include tinymce4.x in my grails project. I am currently using CAS authentication to login. While including the code to import tinymce to my project, it seems that the spring security is blocking the access to the theme and plugin folder of the tinymce library.

Here is my code snippet to include the library

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
    }
);
```

The response thrown by the browser is as follows:-

```
Remote Address:127.0.1.1:8090
Request URL:http://localhost:8090/eve/static/themes/modern/theme.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=811FD6C93D124D9A31264F41CEF11876; activityId=undefined
Host:localhost:8090
Referer:http://localhost:8090/eve/letterSetting/index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Date:Thu, 21 Aug 2014 05:01:56 GMT
Location:http://localhost:8090/eve/login/denied
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

All my request parameter is fine and there is no refrence to either theme or plugin in the requestmap table of springsecurity.

my SpringSecurity config

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.eve.security.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.eve.security.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.eve.security.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.eve.security.Requestmap'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = '/login'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = '/j_spring_cas_security_check'
```

Comment: Can you show us your `staticRules` or `interceptUrlMap` from your `Config.groovy` file?

Comment: It sounds like spring security is blocking the URL for the JS file.  You can use this setting to test if it allows your code to work. `grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false`